# Fetch matching id from postgresql tables when i enter input

Tags: javascript, jquery, postgresql

My Postgresql database contains table

```
| Emp ID | Name | Age | Manager |
|--------|------|-----|---------|
| E001   | A    | 23  | E010    |
| E101   | B    | 19  | E001    |
| E010   | C    | 25  | E101    |
| E241   | D    | 32  | E007    |
```

In my web appplication jsp page contains one text box and 1 submit button 
first we put manager (E010) in to text box and then click submit button and move to next jsp page which contains all data related to (E010).
But my code not working properly 
Please Help

my code is given below

```
  Statement stmt;


{
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
  con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
 String query = "Select manager FROM new ";
 Statement  statement = con.createStatement();
 ResultSet  rs = statement.executeQuery( query);
%>
 <%
while(rs.next())
{
String manager= rs.getString("manager");

%>

<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Manager Code Here......"  />
</div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>


                              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                 <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                       <div class="center"><button type="submit">Submit</button></div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </fieldset>
                        </form>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
```

Comment: Please define "not working properly": What output are you expecting, what are you getting instead, do you get error messages etc.? Also, please indent your code sample.

Comment: @Haem I run the code but it doesn't fetch all data related to E010